# AngularJS : When to use require 'ngmodel' and require options ( ? , ^ ,?^) in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When should I use require: 'ngModel' and require options in directive.

I would be happy if someone could explain this in simple language. What is the benefit of each 
Require options.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS gives you two options in the require option about how to declare requirements with a prefixed character:

```
^ -- Look for the controller on parent elements, not just on the local scope
? -- Don't raise an error if the controller isn't found
```

For more information on this, refer [this](http://www.ng-newsletter.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/posts/directives.html) document, which made it easy for me.